# How to request the app store of a different country?

Tags: python

I want to retrieve the app store HTML page of a certain country. 
I was thinking to use  `request` python package to forge an HTTP GET request, is there any specific header for geolocalisation ? or anything I can use to request the country specific version of the web page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building a scraper for appstore can be done in a few ways. Take apple store for example, the two address below belong to the chart page of Apple app store. You see how CA changed to CN. That is a country code.

```
https://www.apple.com/ca/itunes/charts/

https://www.apple.com/cn/itunes/charts/
```

you can create a function of some sort and use different parameter based on function input. And the code below will only get you started, you still need to concate the entire URL not just parts of it.

```
type_params = {'Canada': {'ca'},
               'China': {'cn'}}

url = 'https://www.apple.com/'
params = {CA}
params.update(type_params[type])
headers = {'User-Agent': ...}

resp = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
```